# Move string into vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, c++11

Is there a way to **move** the content from a std::string into a std::vector? I think with now having rvalue-references in the language this operation would be very useful sometimes.

Comment: what do you mean with "move"?

Comment: Well.. move? move without copying. my_vec = std::move(my_string); (doesn't work obviously)

Comment: I don't know a language which really do a "move". You may copy and then delete/null the source

Comment: @stefanbachert: Then you need to look at C++11 more.

Comment: Internally, strings can differ from vectors, so C++11-style movement of the kind you suggest is probably not possible.

Comment: @cooky451: Please clarify.  Are you trying to move each character into a `vector<char>`?  Are you trying to make a `vector<string>` that just contains that one string?

Comment: @thb No, since C++11 strings are sequence containers just as vectors, so it would be possible if one could get the vector internals.

Comment: @DrewDormann string s = "Hello"; vector<char> v = std::move(s); // v now holds the pointer from s

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, does C++11 does something different than copy and delete/null?

Comment: @stefanbachert Yes. Just google C++11 and take a look at rvalue-references and move semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *theoretically* possible to move from one object type to another. However, those object types have to be designed to allow this. `vector` and `string` are not.

A good clue that an object allows it would be if `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a `std::string&&`. It has no such constructor. Also, `vector` would have to be a friend of `string` to get at its internals.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. No way to tell the string "hey, I need this, please don't delete"?

Comment: @cooky451: Well, considering that many `string`s implement small-string optimization (meaning that strings under a certain length aren't heap-allocated), that would be *impossible* to do. You can't tell a `string` to "please don't delete" something it didn't allocate. Also, note that they can be allocated with different allocators (though admittedly that could be a requirement for move, much like `list::splice`). There are [good reasons why `string` and `vector` are two different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436762).

Comment: Ok, I didn't consider small-string optimization. Well, I think I'll just have to copy it.